# Attaching textarea by v-model to computed with other variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've got input text area that is binded to computed property, as below:

```
<v-text-field
  label="Message"
  v-model="offer"
  multi-line
></v-text-field>
<div v-html="offer"></div>

return {
   var1: "some text",
   var2: "some text2",

   computed: {
      offer () {
         return this.var1 + this.var2 
      },
   }
}
```

My intention is to be able to edit inside `text-field` input text from my variables (do not edit the source of variables) and be able to add them dynamically (like true-false). As far text is showing correctly inside input. Unfortunatelly I've got an error when I start to type or edit:

```
[Vue warn]: Computed property "offer" was assigned to but it has no setter.
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?
Bonus question: how can I make that `var1` and `var2` will show in seperate rows in the `text-field` input?

edit:
I modified my computed into:

```
offer: {
    get() {
        return this.var1 + this.var2
    },
    set() {
      return this.offer
    }
},
```

and it returns the value of those two variables to my html. However I cannot edit this value in my text-field. This is my main problem. I don't want to modify var1 and var2. I want to modify value of this.offer in my text-field.

edit2:

I modified my computed into:

```
offer: {
    get() {
        return this.var1 + this.var2
    },
    set(value) {
      var text = value
      this.offerNew = text
    }
},
```

then I output `{{offerNew}}`

Now it works /some kind of/ and I am able to edit my textfield and output the into html. However when I change `var1: "some text"` into `var1: "some other text inside variable"`. My whole offerNew text resets, but I think this is how computed works...

the result I want to achieve is:

```
textfield:
some text, some text 2, writing something like lorem ipsum

output {{offerNew}} -> some text, some text 2, writing something like lorem ipsum
```

then changing `var1` into "some other text"

want to have:

```
textfield:
some other text, some text 2, writing something like lorem ipsum

output {{offerNew}} -> some other text, some text 2, writing something like lorem ipsum
```

but instead I've got:

```
textfield:
some other text, some text 2
output {{offerNew}} -> some other text, some text 2
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems achievable because you are assuming the user only appends text to the `textarea`. But what if the user edit the middle of content that is from `var1`? There's no way for the code to know it changed a middle of `var1`, `var2` or not.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I want to make app as user friendly as possible and this is harder that I expected :)

Comment: If you have `some text, some text 2, writing something like lorem ipsum` in the text area, and then the user types `AAA`, making it `somAAAe text, some text 2, writing something like lorem ipsum`, and then you change `var1` into `"some other text"` what do you think `offerNew` should be?

Comment: user is able only to add and remove vars, but you are correct, this will restart computed value and that's why I need to try another approach :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you make it set. Change:

```
computed: {
    offer () {
        return this.var1 + this.var2
    },
}
```

To:

```
computed: {
    offer: {
        get() {
            return this.var1 + this.var2
        },
        set(newValue) {
            this.var1 = newValue;
            this.var2 = '';
        }
    },
}
```

Now, mind the logic at the setter. I assigned the new value to `var1` and the empty string to `var2`. Maybe you want something different, like splitting the value in half between those two vars ou something else. Only you can tell.

## Not changing the vars

If you want to use the vars just as base value, the cleaner way is to turn `offer` back into a regular `data` (so it is editable), and *watch* the `var1` and `var2` variables, changing `offer` when one of them changes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    var1: "some text",
    var2: "some text2",
    offer: ''
  },
  created() {
    this.offer = this.var1 + '\n' + this.var2;
  },
  watch: {
    var1: function (newVar1) {
      this.offer = newVar1 + '\n' + this.var2;
    },
    var2: function (newVar2) {
      this.offer = this.var1 + '\n' + newVar2;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeVars() {
      this.var1 = 'i am var1';
      this.var2 = 'var2 is ' + new Date().getSeconds();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-btn @click="changeVars" small>CLICK TO CHANGE var1 and var2</v-btn>
      
      <v-text-field
          label="Message"
          v-model="offer"
          multi-line
      ></v-text-field>
      <div v-html="offer"></div>

    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: you are right, but in my specific case, I don't want to change variables value. I'm using var1 and var2 just as a "base edit" data and output it all to the div and text-input field, without changing vars.

Comment: sorry, it has to be computed because var1 and var2 values are changing @click

Comment: So when they change you just want to overwrite what has been edited at the textarea?

Comment: that's it, but I also want to be able to edit inside textarea. Not changing vars values, but changing all text inside textarea - text from vars and additional. That's tricky :)

Comment: See updated answer. I'm using `watch`. In you case, I believe it will yield a cleaner solution than `computed`.

Comment: maybe. I've managed to make this work with computed this way: 
`set: function(value) {
          var text = value
          this.offerNew = text
        }` and then output `{{offerNew}}`, but this is not changed instantly when I modify var1 in other input and resets after changing vars ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you said, but it seems what you are doing is what `watch` is for. Are you using a `computed`/`offer` and then changing the value of `offerNew` when `offer` is set? Anyway, what from the current solution is not working (so I understand your problem better)?

Comment: I added second edit to my question. Hope this will help you to understand :) however I'm thinking this is much more complex that I expected... sorry for confusing